# Flutter floatingActionButton on modal bottom (without scaffold)

Tags: flutter, modal-dialog, floating-action-button, bottom-sheet

I have a situation in which I want a modal bottom sheet to be visible upon tapping a widget.
This code works correctly (from the widget, which is basically a "card"):

```dart
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
        child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
                    showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
                                expand: false,
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    customiseItemScreen(item: this.item,),
                                );

            },
            ...
            ...
```

However, I'd also like to display a floating action button in the `customiseItemScreen` widget. When there's a scaffold involved, it's easy, to wit:

```dart
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
floatingActionButton:
...
...
```

But since `customiseItemScreen` returns a Material (without a scaffold), the above members do not exist. Is there a better way to go about this or a solution that I may be missing with the existing code?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't know about your customizeItemScreen, since you don't include it, but if you can show  a floating action button wherever you want. If you want it in the modal sheet , your modal should return something like:                                                     `Column(children:[Container1(),Container2(child:FloatingActionButton())]) `

Answer (score 6):

You can use a Stack widget with Positioned widget

```
Stack(
 children: [
  Material(...),
  Positioned(...) //put a button inside and position it with bottom and right
)
```

Comment: Thanks @captain-web,

I was hoping to avoid the `Positioned` widget but it's in fact what I ended up doing as I couldn't find a better solution.

For future copy pasters:

```dart
             Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
                  child: yourChildWidget() 
                  
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Align` with `alignment: Alignment.bottomRight` instead of `Positioned` for the button as follows:

```
Stack(
    children: [
        Material(...),
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Ink(
                    decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {...},
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ],
```