# How to overlap button on BottomSheet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my design, there is a close button in the `BottomSheet`. I have tried `Stack`. But it didn't work. Does anyone know how to achieve the result? Thanks :)

[image: Overlap Button in BottomSheet]

```dart
modalBottomSheet(context) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Text('Sample Text'),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `floatingActionButton` in the app's scaffold, with different locations? I know this can be used to dock the FAB to the bottom navigation, I'm not sure how it'd react to the bottom sheet, though. Check out the options on here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButtonLocation-class.html

Comment: The only related question I could find (which you've propbably already taken a look at) proposes using a `Stack` in combination with a `Postioned` widget to make sure they overlap properly. [link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368709/flutter-floatingactionbutton-on-modal-bottom-without-scaffold)

Comment: Yaa, I have seen it. But `Positioned` and FAB widgets are also not working.

Comment: Hi! I was trying around and found a solution. Check it out below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've been trying around for a bit, and this seems to work as you explained.

```dart
  modalBottomSheet(context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          // using a scaffold helps to more easily position the FAB
          return Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  child: Text("Text in the sheet"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // translate the FAB up by 30
            floatingActionButton: Container(
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -30, 0.0),  // translate up by 30
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // do stuff
                  print('doing stuff');
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ),
            // dock it to the center top (from which it is translated)
            floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerTop,
          );
        });
  }
```

The meat of the solution here is to transform the `Container` which contains the FAB. I got this idea from [this older SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54047013/15469537) to a somewhat related question.

The result looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

You'll probably have to make some more edits to achieve the exact result you desire, but I hope this sets you on the right path.

#### Edit

When, in the above solution, you want to press the FAB, and you tap the top half, the `onPressed` handler fires, but the modal also closes. You should probably use a `WillPopScope` that only pops when the actual button is pressed (and not the area around/above it). If you think it's fine pressing anywhere above it as well, you can just leave it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children: [
              Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20))),
                height: 220.h,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 16),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                         ElevatedButton(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: const Center(child: Text('Remove')))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  top: -30.h,
                  right: 12.w,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Icon(Icons.close),
                  )),
            ]);
          },
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than the existing answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)