# How to create a bottom sheets in Flutter like in (Instagram,snapchat)

Tags: flutter

Can anyone tell how to create this type of bottom sheet . Specifically how to add the notch on the top of the sheet
Thanks in advance:)[image: This is how i need it]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% about the notch on the top, but flutter has a Material Design BottomSheet class.

Here is how to implement it
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) anyway i'm looking for a bottom sheet with notch

Comment: Also check out https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html
it seems to be more customizable, although I have never tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `BottomSheet`'s shape round using the `shape` parameter of `showModalBottomSheet` (code from [other SA answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52123492/15469537)):

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
  ),
  ...
);
```

It might already work to simply put the contents of the sheet inside a column, starting with a simple rectangle that can act like the notch. AFAIK there's no built-in way to do this.

If that doesn't place it high enough, I explained [as a response to another question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68155726/15469537) how to overlay a shape, in that case a FAB, on top of the sheet, by creating a scaffold inside the sheet. You could do something similar as well.